# AXIS2/Tomcat WSDL generation

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat, soap, apache-axis

I have a strange problem when deploying my SOAP webservice built using AXIS2

When deploying I get 8 out of 10 time the following message when I navigate to my WSDL:

```
<error>  
   <description>Unable to generate WSDL 1.1 for this service</description>  
   <reason>If you wish Axis2 to automatically generate the WSDL 1.1, then please set    useOriginalwsdl as false in your services.xml</reason>  
</error>
```

But the strange thing is that 2 out of 10 times I does find the WSDL file, therefore I think that my settings are correct, It's just strange that is sometimes works and sometimes not...

Anyone got an idea what might be wrong here?

thank you for the help

Comment: Did you ever find out the cause?

Comment: @AdamRofer No, But I did found out that my webservice was available even without the WSDL generation. But I still experience this problem, so if you have the same thing and are able to fix it, please let me know...

Comment: This mechanism changed in Axis2 1.6 to fix a nullpointer, try upgrading Axis2. Alternatively, try ?wsdl2 or do what the error says and set the useOriginalwsdl to false...